# Content Manager VS Resource Manager VS Asset Manager

Tags: c#, .net, monogame, resourcemanager

When creating a class that will handle the game contents/resources/assets and using the MonoGame framework, which is the best to use as a name for the class and why? Is it the `ContentManager.cs`, `ResourceManager.cs` or `AssetManager.cs`?

I am aware that `ContentManager.cs` is already a class in the MonoGame framework classes under `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content` namespace as well as the `ResourceManager.cs` that is already a class in the .NET Base Class Library (BCL) under the `System.Resources` namespace.

And I am very particular with naming so I am confused right now. As a personal preference, I will leave the `AssetManager.cs` because I don't prefer it myself. That leaves the `ContentManager.cs` and `ResourceManager.cs` as the options for me. But can you enlighten me which is the best way to name a class that will handle all the game contents/resources/assets of the game? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you doing in this class, apart from loading assets? Because if nothing else, why not just use ContentManager directly?

Comment: I am using the class for loading, unloading and accessing of game contents/resources/assets...

Comment: But Microsofts ContentManager already does this for you. Are you not doing anything more than that in your class?

Comment: Hmmm. I don't follow on what you are saying, maybe I haven't yet done the option you are saying. The reason why I implemented this class is to serve as a repository for all assets (graphics, music, sounds, fonts, etc). The ContentManager.cs sure do the loading and unloading. But I want an implementation where I can easily access my assets pretty much like a repository of assets.